# Find all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}.x^2+y^2+z^2+x+y+z=1$

Tags: number-theory

Find all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}$

where.$x^2+y^2+z^2+x+y+z=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $u^2 + v^2 + w^2 = 7 t^2$ where $u/t = 2x+1$, $v/t = 2y+1$, $w/t=2z+1$ and $u,v,w,t$ are integers with no common factor and $t \ne 0$.  Now consider this mod $8$.

Comment: Thanks.I've already thought about it.:)

Answer (score 2):

Assume $(x,y,z)$ is sastifying the equation.

We can multiply $K=N^2(N \in \mathbb{Z}^+)$ to the both sides of equation.

And the both sides are integers.

Set $N=2^{h}s$,$s$ is odd.

Then $K((2x+1)^2+(2y+1)^2+(2z+1)^2)=7N^2$

The $LHS$ is sum of 3 squares.

From A production by Gauss, $a^2+b^2+c^2=m,(a,b,c,m,\alpha,t \in\mathbb{N})$$\Leftrightarrow m\ne 4^{\alpha}(8t+7)$

Because,$s^2 \equiv 1\pmod{8}\Rightarrow 7s^2 \equiv 7 \pmod{8}$

Which is impossible!